Linkedin: "serviceErrorCode: N/A" When attempting to create ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS webhook
I am attempting to create a webhook subscription for ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS, but when I make the request, I get in response HTTP status code: 403, serviceErrorCode: N/A.
Usually there is a service error code associated with my request, which is what bring me here. Has anyone seen something like this before? Or know what might be causing the serviceErrorCode to be N/A?
This is the request which I am making
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:{application_id},user:urn:li:person:{user_id},entity:urn:li:organization:{organization_id},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)

In response I am getting HTTP status code: 403, serviceErrorCode: N/A.
If it fails, I am expecting something in the serviceErrorCode.
Thanks y'all!
